# Bash shell script to get email When New file comes Without Inotify

Tags: bash, shell, sh

Is there any why to create Bash shell script which send all new incoming file information ( filename; arriving date/time; filesize) into certain folder.

i can not use inotify so please do not consider it as option.

Comment: To get an email or to send it into a certain folder?

Comment: `bash` itself does not monitor your file system. If you cannot use `inotify` because you are not running under Linux, there are similar tools for other operating systems.

Comment: Lucio Just get email with above information, that's it

Comment: chepner 
we can write script or scripts and schedule them for certain time gap.
but i can not install any tools or script on that server. So i have only Shell script option

Comment: I got Little bit of IDEA that how we can do this....
but i dont know how to turn it into the codes.
if you have some idea or code, Most welcome

Comment: Are you asking how to process incoming emails?  Or how to monitor a folder for, say, ftp uploads?

Comment: @tripleee i am saying 
Let there is a directory in server /xyz
and p, q and r files are coming in that directory(via ftp uploading or via any application)
i want to receive an email with File name like q, p or r 
when it comes and the size of file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

monitor_dir=/path/to/dir
email=me@me.com

files=$(find "$monitor_dir" -maxdepth 1 | sort)
IFS=$'\n'

while true
do
  sleep 5s

  newfiles=$(find "$monitor_dir" -maxdepth 1 | sort)
  added=$(comm -13 <(echo "$files") <(echo "$newfiles"))

  [ "$added" != "" ] &&
    find $added -maxdepth 1 -printf '%Tc\t%s\t%p\n' |
    mail -s "incoming" "$email"

  files="$newfiles"
done
```

This should work well as long as there are no files created containing newlines in their names. Other caveats are that I can't see any option for `find` to output a human readable size, so getting that would require further processing. Also most filesystems don't actually store file creation time, modification time is used instead (not that it makes any real difference in this case).

#### Update

To test the script and have it print to a terminal just remove the `mail` line and the pipe (`|`) at the end of the previous line. I changed the monitor directory to a variable at the top rather than just directly coded, so fill in the directory here. Then put the script into a file, set executable permissions and run (`./filename` when in the scripts directory). If you put files into your directory, they should appear on the script's console after a few seconds.

To send emails, you need to make sure your system is set up to send emails from the command line. Your distro should have instructions for that. You can send a test email with:

```
<<<hello mail -s "test email" some@email.com
```

If you don't want to set up for sending emails, it is also possible to email a local system user at `username@localhost`. You can check this with the `mail` command or it is possible to set up a different mail reader like Thunderbird.

Comment: Not actually parsing the output of `ls` here, just removing the top line. But otherwise, `find` is much better to work with here, so will update the answer to use that.

Comment: Yes, you are right @Graeme the size of file which comes out after ls -ltr is sufficient.
and 
Date could be anyone modification or creation. because in the case of new files both are same

Comment: @SirAthos i read that article. can you please tell me if we not parse the output of ls then what other option we can opt in this case.

Comment: @Graeme can you please tell me, how to test it. and how we get the mail. or echo the output

Comment: why i am not getting any mail ?
how i can fix this

Comment: Updated. You will need to set up your system for email or use a local address.

Comment: Great work @Graeme thank you so much. i was looking for the same

Comment: @Readerlook You can use bash builtins instead of parsing `ls` or `find`. I'll add an answer with the details, for didactic purpose.

Comment: @Graeme Above script is working fine. i need little enhancement. i want to run this via cron job in which is run check sned mail stop then again after 15 min run rcheck send mail stop. Can you please suggest me the code change ???

Comment: If you want to run the script from cron, just remove the `while` loop (everything highlighted in blue) and the sleep. This will make it finish after a single check/send rather than keep running.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to check for new files, which doesn't use `ls` or `find`, and works with inbox format files too (where all messages are stored in sequence in a single file) is using bash builtins.

The more elegant solution will only work if your inbox is otherwise unmonitored (i.e. mail comes in, gets written to the file, and nobody reads it):

```
#!/bin/bash

inbox_dir=/path/to/dir

while true; do
    for f in "$inbox_dir"/*; do
        [ -N "$f" ] && {
            head -1 "$f" >/dev/null
            echo "unread stuff in file: $f"
        }
    done
    sleep 5
done
```

Another solution, which also works while the mail files are being accessed (read), uses timestamps:

```
#!/bin/bash

stamp=/tmp/email_monitor.stamp
inbox_dir=/path/to/dir

touch "$stamp"
while true; do
    mv "$stamp" "$stamp.old"
    touch "$stamp"
    for f in "$inbox_dir"/*; do
        [ "$f" -nt "$stamp.old" -a "$f" -ot "$stamp" ] && {
            echo "new stuff in file: $f"
        }
    done
    rm -f "$stamp.old"
    sleep 5
done
```

Comment: @athos, I think you have misunderstood the question. The idea is to monitor for newly created files rather than changes to existing ones. My reason for using `find` (and initially `ls`) over shell globbing was for the ease of generating a newline separated list of files to store and compare.

Comment: @sirAthos thanks for the effort but my issue is solved. i have one more problem if you can help me in that i will be very thankful. link is as follows:
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21281454/how-to-format-the-mail-output-of-bash-shell-script

Comment: @Graeme: If I understand the mail directory format correctly, mails are delivered one-per-file, and that file is never modified after delivery (only deleted or moved), so watching for any changes in the directory should work correctly. The reason I wouldn't recommend `ls`-type solutions is because they fail on filenames containing `\n` - even though, on mail directories, such naming is unlikely to occur.

Comment: @Readerlook: I'm glad your problem is solved. I posted this answer as a reply to your follow-up question (and deliberately after you accepted Graeme's answer). The purpose of this site is to help the community, not just the OP, and so my hope is that an alternate approach with its own advantages may prove useful to someone one day.

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggled about a similar problem.

I needed a script that runs only once the day (via cron).

Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

email=my@mail.com
files=/path/to/file

if test -d "/path/to/somewhere"
then

  find $files -newermt '1 day ago' -printf '%Tc\t%s\t%p\n' |
  mail -s "Subject" "$email"

else

  echo "The path doesn't exist..." | mail -s "Subject" "$email"

fi
exit
```