# How to format The mail Output of Bash Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell, email, sh

I have a Bash shell script which send an email in every day at certain time.
the code is as follows:

```
first_dir=/test1 second_dir=/test2

email=me@me.com

allfiles=$(find /test1 /test2 -maxdepth 1 | sort) IFS=$'\n'

while true do sleep 24h

[ "$allfiles" != "" ] &&
    find $allfiles -maxdepth 1 -printf '%Tc\t%s\t%p\n' |
    mail -s "List Of All Files" "$email"

files="$allfiles"  

done
```

This script is giving output in Single column.
but I want the Output in two columns.

- 1st column with files of first_dir=/test1
- 2nd column with files of second_dir=/test2

Comment: First: you should use [crontab](http://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab) for scheduling for a certain time. This will execute every 24h at the time the script is started.

Comment: @PeterMmm scheduling and running is not the issue. What i want is a clear list of files in the mail in two separate columns so that i can perform analysis easily

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want them separated like that, don't join them together in the first place

```
first_dir=/test1
second_dir=/test2
while sleep 24h; do
    first_files=$(find $first_dir -maxdepth 1 -printf '%Tc\t%s\t%p\n')
    second_files=$(find $second_dir -maxdepth 1 -printf '%Tc\t%s\t%p\n')
    paste <(sort -t $'\t' -k 3,3 <<< "$first_files") \
          <(sort -t $'\t' -k 3,3 <<< "$second_files") |
    mail -s "List Of All Files" "$email"
done
```

Comment:  This would be even better without the `sleep` and in a cron job.

Comment: YES I will use cron in that.

Comment: As mentioned earlier...  the basic need/requirement is a clear list of files in two directories in one email.

Comment: You want to use `|` instead of `\t`? OK, then do it. It's that simple.